# Does food become nonkosher when it is touched by someone who didn't do negal vassar?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, netilat-yadayim-washing, ruach-rah

I've heard that there is a concept of ruach ra on one's hands before doing negal vassar and that a person shouldn't touch food.
What if they did though? Can they and other people eat it?

Answer (score 2):

[Shulchan Aruch Harav](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/1/4/2.htm) says one must be extremely careful without offering any remedy:

> וכל שכן שצריך ליזהר מאד שלא ליגע קודם נטילה בשום מאכל או משקה שלא לטמאם וצריך להזהיר הנשים על זה ביותר כי רוב תיקון המאכלים הוא על ידן

The [Mishna Berura](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93#%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%94) says you may eat it after rinsing it three times:

> ואם נגע במאכל קודם שנטל ידיו, אין לאסור המאכל על ידי זה; אבל לכתחילה מאוד יש ליזהר שלא ליגע אז בשום מאכל. ואם נגע באוכל, ידיחנו שלוש פעמים

Comment: The Mishnah Berurah says you may eat it, and separately he says you should rinse it 3 times. But it doesn't sound like one depends on the other.